# Make a class method to count the comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning the Ruby on Rails and I would like to make a class methods to count the article comments.
I am creating this class method

```
class_methods do
   def comment_count

   end
end
```

And this is my schemas

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "status", default: "public"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "commenter"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "article_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "status"
    t.index ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "articles"
```

Comment: comments are related to articles and I assume the relationships are set up in the models?  Just pass the article to that method, `def comment_count(article)`  and then  return `article.comments.count` should do it.  Depending on how you use it you may want to check `article.comments.any?` before returning something but that is up to you and your needs.

Comment: @RockwellRice Hi at the Article model I have `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy` and the Comment model: `belongs_to :article`

Comment: yep so getting the comments count for an article would just look like this depending on the type of variable you are using, `article.comments.count`

Comment: One doubt, is it better to create a visible module? Because I tried to put at the Visible Module and did not work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but using those relationships is a perfectly normal Rails convention.

Comment: I tried this at Visible Module `class_methods do
    def comment_count
      article.comment.count
    end
  end` and I put this `<%= Article.comment_count %>` but did not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232429/discussion-between-vagner-wentz-and-rockwell-rice).

Comment: This appears to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking us about what you think is the solution (a class method defined in a module) - instead of actually asking about the problem you're trying to solve. Tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish and focus less on the nuts and bolts. Its very unclear what the actual goal is here - to create a scope that gets all the articles and selects a count of the comments belonging to that article? To get the comment count of an individual article?